# Do I need a front end framework/bundler/typescript if I alreadymade my Js?

Tags: reactjs, web, sass, frontend, web-frontend

I am learning Web development by making a web app and I have completed the front end with html, css and javascript. However, I saw a video about roadmaps that said i need a framework and other stuff like sass, bootstrap, react, typescript etc. I will also be making a database and i don't know if I need it for that. Do I need anything else if I have finished my fronted with just html css and js?

I have looked into react, and bootstrap but I dont think I need them

Comment: No, you don’t need anything else. But it’s a good idea you learn those things later. For now I’d suggest stick to your plan and use vanilla JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your work fit your need you can keep it the way it is.
But i would recommend you to get into frameworks and librairies like react to improve you web apps performances.

Comment: In almost all circumstances, lib like react will hinder performance, not improve it. What they do is to make development easier or more enjoyable by handling lower level logic for you, so you can focus on higher level logic that matters more.